# Windows will slow down app loading if not online for some time

Tags: c#, windows, performance, updates, antivirus

a very specific problem that I can not find an old thread of.

We have a C# app developed and confused running on a Windows 10 machine updated to latest version. We are talking about a closed system that does not have an internet connection at all, except when installing everything.

Now at beginning the app loads reasonably fast. This means 0-2s for the splash screen as this is the first thing that we display. All good.

After 14 days approx. the app load time goes to 30s. This means that after initial click it takes between 20-30s for the splash screen to appear.
How to solve it? Connect the PC online for 5 minutes and again the load time is down to 0s for another 14 days... (not acceptable once the system is handed over)

Defender = have exceptions on directories and executables (no other AV in use)

Firewall = disabled

What could be the problem? Windows seems to be searching for something online. But what, it does not seem to download anything specific.

Comment: You might try looking at what's going on using SysInternals' _Process Monitor_ tool.  You can see what files and registry entries are being accessed

Comment: Is that your app? Can you see in the code? If not - most likely some "trial" period ended, or just looking for a possible update.

Comment: Thanks, Flydog57, will check on that
Hi @Vlad, yes our code, no connections to the web at all.

Answer (score 0):

The app (both exe and libraries) probably has a digital signature. The timestamp of the signature is verified on a remote server (you should be able to see this in `Fiddler` or `Postman`). Windows probably caches the result to avoid this network delay, but (just guessing now) for security reasons it cannot cache it forever. 14 days seems like a reasonable trade-off.

You can try to remove the signature and see if the error goes away. See [SignTool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signtool) for details.